# Garmin Edge 520 kees switching to navigation screen when riding a course

Tags: garmin

On my Garmin Edge 520, when I ride a course, the display always keeps switching to the map screen even if I manually scroll to some other screen with a few data fields. Can I disable this behavior so I can manually switch to maps when I need to?

Comment: It can be disabled in settings.

Comment: @Carel I'm afraid you'll have to be a little more specific.

Comment: It's all in the manual!